# Can static array store different values of two objects?

Tags: c++, object, multidimensional-array, static

As I am practicing my C++, I was wondering if it is possible to store different values of two objects for static array within class.

For example:

We have a class with a two dimensional array 3x3 which is static float, then two objects are created and passed to fill my array.

```
class Matrix{

public:
    Matrix();
    void fillArr(string arr_nmb);
    void printArr();
    friend Matrix addMatrix(Matrix &, Matrix &);
private:
    static float arr[3][3];
    int size = 3;
};

float Matrix::arr[3][3] = {};

Matrix::Matrix(){
    arr[3][3] = { 0 };
}

void Matrix::fillArr(string arr_nmb){
        cout << "Fill "<< arr_nmb << " : " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                cin >> arr[i][j];
            }
}

void Matrix::printArr(){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          cout << " " << arr[i][j] << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
}

Matrix addMatrix(Matrix &, Matrix&){
    Matrix*p;

    return *p;
}  

int main(){ 

    Matrix m1;
    Matrix m2;

    m1.fillArr("1");
    m1.printArr();
    m2.fillArr("2");
    m2.printArr();
    cout << endl;
    m1.printArr();
    cout << endl;
    m2.printArr();

    while (1) if (kbhit()) break;
    return 1;
}
```

For static arr, it prints last fill from m2.fillArr("2");
But in case I delete static from arr declaration it prints different values from m1 and m2 objects.

Is there any way to get same result for static as it is for non-static?

Comment: If you want the array to behave as-if it weren't `static` then don't make it `static`. You should explain why you want it to be `static` if you want it to have different values for different `Matrix` instances.

Comment: I got it within my excercise that it should be static

Comment: `arr[3][3] = { 0 };` doesn't initialize the array to zero. It tries to set the value of the element at index `[3][3]` which is out of bounds and Undefined Behavior.

Comment: It does, if I print after that constructor, then it prints whole zeroes within array.
Although I can change it to two fors.

Comment: That is incorrect. `static` members are zero initialized, so the array starts with all zeroes. That may be what you are observing. If you construct another `Matrix` after filling the array, you will see it is probably not reset to zero. See : https://godbolt.org/z/8qz9fa1js Edit : if you mean you could change it to `arr[4][4]` that is also incorrect. You can only use `= { 0 };` to initialize an array. It won't work to assign new values to an existing array because `[ ]` is used to access individual elements after that point.

Comment: @GunhasizSeytan, no, it does not initialize. François Andrieux is right. Call fillArr() => create another object (just declare) and make output.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I meant this 
`for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 0;`

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, there is no way to let it be static and I have to operate on non-static array to have different values with two objects, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is the entire point.  You seem to have unfortunately learned `static` first.  Normally, people learn about `static` later.  I think you've confused `static` as being something important for arrays.  Its purpose is completely orthogonal to that.  Regarding the init, just `std::fill(arr, arr+9, 0);` would do it.

Comment: That's correct. When you declare a member variable static there is only one instance of it and it is shared with all objects. Very different from declaring a static in a function where it is retained between function calls..

Comment: Google is your friend ...  A search for "c++ static float" finds 10+ related items, with even more info that you will want to know.

Comment: @2785528 StackOverflow is my friend too, there is plenty of fine developers who love to help such rookies as I.

Thank you guys, now I understand :)